# Is this question too broad?

Tags: discussion

re: [How do different strings (of the same gauge) affect the tone?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14190/how-do-different-strings-affect-the-tone)

I *would* like to see questions about this sort of thing. But this one just seems too *all over the place*.

Would it be better to have several separate questions about different aspects of comparing strings? We have a few questions covering guage already. But I don't think we have anything comparing the component metals, and that's something I'd like to see. Wrappings seems rather obvious from the names (roundwound, groundwound, compressed roundwound, flatwound; and "tapewound" is already covered).

Um. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

It should probably be made into two or more different questions. The first one being what makes strings of the same gauge have different tones and then each answer (i.e. marital, manufacturing process, ect) get its own question on how it affect the tone of strings . This will at least give a more in depth answer for each part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Well I thought about splitting it at first, but I thought it could lead to a really good answer. You have read about a million times how gauge does affect the sound, but I haven't found a detailed and well written answer somewhere that talks about all other aspects you may want to consider when you need to chose which strings you should buy.
As I said in the question itself, I don't know to much about it, so the question might be to broad, but I couldn't say.

But I think it could helpfull for a lot of "googlers" having it all together when they get to this question themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Just changing the title to reflect that it's a question about brand or the materials used to construct the string would improve the question.

Comment: If it's about brand I would want to close it - we don't want to encourage product recommendation answers.

Answer (score -1):

I voted to close the question, then retracted when I realised he was talking about brand, not gauge.

I think it would be worth doing a jeopardy-style "tell me all about strings" question (to complement my [How does string gauge affect a guitar's sound and playability?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/4593/how-does-string-gauge-affect-a-guitars-sound-and-playability) which is all about gauge.

But I dunno. As far as I'm concerned, even good strings are cheap, and unless you buy cheese wire, they're all about as good as each other. Just get whatever's in the shop and be happy.